# What are the differences between `bundle exec rake release` and `gem push`?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler, executable

I'd like to know the difference between using `bundle exec rake release` to publish a gem.  Is there any benefit over `gem push` in terms of `rake` catching a runtime error?

**Specifically** I ask this in context of `executable gems` that run on one's terminal **independently** of `irb`.

For example: if my `/bin/my_gem` is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require '../lib/my_gem'
```

And `.gemspec` contains

```
s.bindir = "bin"#or even "exe"
s.executables = ["my_gem"]#or s.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
s.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Would `bundle exec rake release` perhaps catch a misconfiguration that `gem push` would miss?

Comment: I dont think that either command does some checks for misconfiguration (if you found some indications for that, please include the reference in your question). However, I believe that the rake task does cover more aspects of the release-cycle, like adding a tag to the git repository etc., while gem push just does the upload to rubygems.org (or any other gem-server).

Comment: so I was wondering if `bundle exec rake <command>` caught any misconfiguration between specifications like `s.bindir` and `s.executables` (in case one uses `bin` in one and `exe` in the other, etc.).  `gem push` nor `gem build` really catch anything (I could be wrong?)

Comment: That would be really easy to test, wouldnt it?

Comment: Release builds, tags, and pushes the gem; it can identify additional oversights like dirty files, invalid tags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like `release` because it packages together best-practice release actions (tagging/validating tag is not a duplicate/building/pushing the gem), and the last time I used gem push I recall it being irritatingly fiddly. Running `bundle exec rails --tasks` in your gem's repository shows the description of each task (including `release`), and you can read the [GemHelper source code](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/bf1a8cb729f7c00e5345e58e23be56e6fec52cf7/bundler/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb#L67) for more detail.

Your gemspec should set `metadata['allowed_push_host']`, which is intended to support releases via the task. If you're using Github's registry to host a private gem, you will need to set `BUNDLE_GEM__PUSH_KEY=github` to ensure the gem is pushed to the host with the arg `--key github` and define the credential config needed to authenticate with your host (check the [bundler manual](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/25fc469869e1d21d78be4d7c01475d78e0435e14/bundler/lib/bundler/man/bundle-config.1.ronn#list-of-available-keys) and Github documentation for more detail).

Comment: I think you mean `bundle exec rake --tasks` not `bundle exec rails --tasks`

Comment: @PaulPettengill I think I definitely meant what I said (unless you're tragically trapped in time 8 years ago? Poor you!). https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22288 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1e4f12c12c7d9f4c56eb8acff5f4a4f849f09fd8/railties/test/command/help_integration_test.rb#L48